# ValueError: y has more than n_class unique elements

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, torch

I keep getting this error: ValueError: y has more than n_class unique elements. when running this code:

```
!pip install --pre deepchem

import deepchem as dc
dc.version
import pandas as pd
import torch
import tensorflow as tf

featurizers = dc.feat.CoulombMatrix(max_atoms=23)
splitter = "stratified"
tasks, datasets, transformers = dc.molnet.load_qm7(featurizer = featurizers, split = splitter)
train_dataset, valid_dataset, test_dataset = datasets

metric = dc.metrics.Metric(dc.metrics.roc_auc_score)
model = dc.models.DTNNModel(n_tasks = 23*23, n_class = 1)
model.fit(train_dataset, nb_epoch = 50)
print('training set score:', model.evaluate(train_dataset, [metric]))
print('test set score:', model.evaluate(test_dataset, [metric]))
```

when I try the following:

```
prediction = model.predict(test_dataset)
print(len(train_dataset.y))
print(len(prediction))
print(len(prediction[1]))
```

I get this output:
5470
684
529
I think the problem lies with my model. Its supposed to take the coulomb matrix (23*23) as an input and give me the corresponding energy as a single int but for some reason its giving me the energy as a vector and I am not getting the same number of inputs and outputs.

I think the problem is that the DTNN model isn't set to `y = 1` but how can I change that?

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `model.summary`?

Comment: When I tried running model.summary() I receiver the error: AttributeError: 'DTNNModel' object has no attribute 'summary'

Comment: I have identified the problem but I have no idea how to solve it. For some reason when the model processes the 23*23 input (coulomb matrix) the result isn't an integer as its supposed to be (model = dc.models.DTNNModel(n_tasks = 23*23,* n_class = 1*)) It is a vector with different values and the total output of the model for a given dataset is smaller than what its supposed to be which leads to problems during the validation step due to the metric function. Ill update the question.